# How can I force mousePressEvent to refire if the mouse button is held down?

Tags: qt4

I have a widget I am writing and when the mouse button is pressed it takes an action. I need it to repeat if the mouse-button is not released. What is the proper way to achieve this?

Currently I am using a single-shot timer to repeat while pressed, but it seems like this isn't the proper 'QT' way.

Answer (score 0):

Your method seems like a reasonable one since it doesn't appear that the Qt API has an appropriate built-in event.

Answer (score 0):

If your widget is acting like a UI button (and most uses I can think of for this are for widgets acting like a button), you could inherit from [`QAbstractButton`](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractbutton.html).  You would still need to provide your own drawing, but this widget provides an [autoRepeat](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractbutton.html#autoRepeat-prop) property (and associated tuning parameters) to repeatedly emit the clicked signal if the user holds down the mouse button over the widget.  It does not appear, however, that it triggers the event handlers.

Alternately, you could check out the source code for the class to see how they implement it themselves.